# What is this css structure called?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, sharetribe

I am working on my first web dev project, with someone, and I am responsible for the front-end part. In my personal projects I've been using plain css, but in this template I have seen that they are using something else, a different structure, I think. I kind of figure it out how it works, but because I never crossed paths with it before, it makes developing hard for me. I would like to know what it is so I can read some documentation and understand it better. (as an example: usually ,when I use className, I put the class name between "", but here is like css.something)  Can you tell me what it is ? I will leave a snippet here

```css
.menuItem {
  @apply --marketplaceListingAttributeFontStyles;
  color: var(--matterColor);
  /* Layout */
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Override button styles */
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    color: var(--matterColorDark);
  }
  &:hover .menuItemBorder {
    width: 6px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button className={css.menuItem} onClick={()=> this.selectOption(queryParamName, option.key, dates)}>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is `CSS Modules` and you can read more about this usage of CSS in these 2 links:

- [link1](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)
- [link2](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not overly familiar with React, this (`className={css.menuItem}`) is some sort of model binding so that when React has done it's thing it will bind the value of `css.menuItem` to the rendered HTML probably ending up with something like

```
<button className=".menuItem" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript format you see there is a view binding, or something we might describe as a Domain Specific Language (DSL). It is Javascript used by some framework (likely React or another frontend framework) to build the HTML you see on the page. I can't be certain since I don't know what framework I'm looking at, but I'm willing to bet that if you use the "inspect" feature in your browser, you will see this in the resulting HTML that is created by that Javascript:

```
<button class="menuItem" onClick="[...]">
```

This format should look familiar to you if you are expecting plain HTML. That Javascript you linked to just builds this HTML dynamically. In the example you provided, the curly braces (`{ }`) are just an indicator to the Javascript library that it need to fill in that placeholder with something, in this case `css.menuItem`, which translates to a class name of `menuItem` rendered into a css class tag (`class="menuItem"`).

Comment: It is reactjs here, sorry, I forgot to mention. But why woul you use CSS like this? It is not more complicated for no reason ?

Comment: You would use this because it's more flexible. This example is pretty simple, but you might, for example, have a block of Javascript that fills in a different class name based on a bunch of conditions. On the simple end, it could be a boolean conditional statement choosing between two classes, or in a more complex example it could be a function that generates a class name as a Javascript string that changes depending on lots of factors. The key word in my answer is "dynamic". Because the class is assigned in JS rather than hard coded, it can change based on all sorts of factors.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into what that `css` object holds?

From what I can see, the `@apply` puts the css part to be in pre-compiled language like `SASS` or `SCSS`.

You have not mentioned if it is ReactJS. If it is then there is a high possibility that whatever you are dealing with is in JSS.

Comment: Question is tagged with [reactjs]

Comment: It is reactJS, sorry, I didn't mention

Comment: Oops....kinda overlooked that. Putting it in the title would've made it clearer.